# GET from DataBase just one thing

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

im trying to get just The ride(one) from the ManyToMany relation from the passenger route.

Here are the models

```
class Route(models.Model):
    """
   Route model for Retrive a Route M FROM GOOGLE API
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='route')
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car, related_name='car', null = True, default= None)
    status = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    on_ride = models.BooleanField(default = False)

class Ride(models.Model):
    """
    Ride model for manage the optimized Route
    """
    seats_available = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default = 0)
    d_route = models.ForeignKey(Route, related_name= 'd_route')
    p_route =  models.ManyToManyField(Route, related_name= 'p_route',blank = True)
```

This is my view if i sent a d_route(Driver Route) ID i can retrieve the Ride  but if i try with a p_route(Passenger Route) the server returns Ride matching query does not exist.

This is the View

```
  class RideOrRoute(APIView):
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = ()  # (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get(self, request, route_id):

        route = Route.objects.get(id = route_id)

        try:
            ride= Ride.objects.get(d_route = route)
            serialized_data = {'id': ride.id ,'geocoded_waypoints': json.loads(ride.geocoded_waypoints), 'routes': json.loads(ride.routes) }
            return Response(serialized_data, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
        except:
            try:
                ride = Ride.objects.get(p_route = route.id)
                serialized_data = {'id': ride.id ,'geocodedwaypoints': json.loads(ride.geocoded_waypoints), 'routes': json.loads(ride.routes) }
                return Response(serialized_data, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except:
                serialized_data= {'id': route.id ,'geocoded_waypoints': json.loads(route.geocoded_waypoints), 'routes': json.loads(route.routes) } #json.loads(request_data.read()) })
        return Response(serialized_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

notice if The driver doesn't have a ride yet i retrieve the route information only

Comment: Maybe there's simply no matching data. No matching query means there's no data matching the querying criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an error in your code.
Try changing

```
ride = Ride.objects.get(p_route = route.id)
```

to

```
ride = Ride.objects.get(p_route = route)
```